Was anyone below 17 coming from durmstrang and beauxbatons?
The age criteria for entering Tri-wizard tournament was 17 years or more. So why was Ron thinking that anyone below 17 was coming from durmstrang and beauxbatons?

"Nearly six," said Ron, checking his watch and then staring down the
drive that led to the front gates. "How d'you reckon they're coming?
The train?"
"I doubt it," said Hermione.
"How, then? Broomsticks?" Harry suggested, looking up at the starry
sky.
"I don't think so...not from that far away...."
"A Portkey?" Ron suggested. "Or they could Apparate - maybe you're
allowed to do it under seventeen wherever they come from?"

